# How to make a program that does not display the console window?

Tags: windows, console, rust

I'm trying to develop a program that uses the sdl2 library. It works perfectly so far, but when I run the program I get two windows - the sdl2 window and the console window.

How can I hide or not create the console window? Maybe there is some sort of `WinMain`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[Rust 1.18](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/06/08/Rust-1.18.html) introduced a Windows Subsystem attribute. Turn off the console with:

```
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]
```

---

When the Rust binaries are linked with the GCC toolchain, to start a program without spawning a command line window we need to [pass the `-mwindows` option to the linker](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-01/msg00225.html).

Cargo [has a `cargo rustc` mode](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/595) which can be used to pass extra flags to `rustc`. Before that was introduced, [there was no known way to pass an option to the compiler with Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/544).

When we can not affect the compilation or linking to the desired effect, one workaround is to hide the window after it has been created:

```
fn hide_console_window() {
    use std::ptr;
    use winapi::um::wincon::GetConsoleWindow;
    use winapi::um::winuser::{ShowWindow, SW_HIDE};

    let window = unsafe {GetConsoleWindow()};
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow
    if window != ptr::null_mut() {
        unsafe {
            ShowWindow(window, SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
}
```

We'll need the following in Cargo.toml to compile the example:

```
[dependencies]
winapi = {version = "0.3", features = ["wincon", "winuser"]}
```

When we are running the program from an existing console or IDE:

```
fn hide_console_window() {
    unsafe { winapi::um::wincon::FreeConsole() };
}
```

This second method doesn't work if we're starting the application from a batch file, for the batch still owns the console and keeps its from disappearing.

Comment: Thank you for such helpful answer. I will wait for several hours for other answers and accept your if nothing better does not emerge :)

Comment: Sure, I'll be happy to learn of a batter solution even if it takes three years.

Comment: @ArtemGr [`GetConsoleWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a handle to the console window.

Comment: @FrancisGagné and ArtemGr you both rock! I've tried the later solution with GetConsoleWindow - it works as expected. Waiting for the option to disable creation of console window at all...

Comment: If you launch the program from cmd or powershell, then calling GetConsoleWindow() and ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) make the console window disappear (but not exit). Perhaps it is better to call FreeConsole() instead.

Comment: @yonran Nice catch. Isn't always the right thing to do, though, so I mention both.

Comment: I've found a solution. Check my answer below.

Comment: This seems to completely disable console output so that running the executable from a command line doesn't yield in any output. I used `#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]` to only disable the console when compiling with `--release`

Comment: what if i'm not compiling for windows? how do i hide the console then?

Comment: @HiddenToad "Not for Windows" is likely too broad. You might want to look up a platform-specific solution elsewhere. (Answers specific to platform X would be harder to find when they are given under a question for platform Y.)

Answer (score 15):

Soon, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37501 will land, which is an implementation of [RFC 1665](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1665-windows-subsystem.md) and the correct answer will be

```
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]
```

in your crate root.

Comment: This is already mentioned in the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29764309/155423).

Comment: Ah! I missed it

Comment: As a comment on the top answer mentions, "This seems to completely disable console output so that running the executable from a command line doesn't yield in any output. "

Comment: Remember to put this at the very top of your main.rs file! This messed with me for a minute.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to Roman Quick's answer if you're using the MSVC toolchain you'll want to pass MSVC linker args instead.

```
cargo rustc --release -- -Clink-args="/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup"
```

Answer (score 9):

After some time I've found a perfect answer!
Cargo now has very useful subcommand - `rustc`.

The full build command is like this:

```
cargo rustc -- -Clink-args="-Wl,--subsystem,windows"
```

Now we can build debug builds with regular `cargo build`, and when we need to make a final build we can use this command:

```
cargo rustc --release -- -Clink-args="-Wl,--subsystem,windows"
```

Comment: This answer only applies if you are using GCC, not the MSVC toolchain. Please see GhotiPhud's answer below if you're using the MSVC toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I hide or not create the console window?

It may be that you can use a creation flag to indicate no window.

```
winapi = {version = "0.3.9", features = ["winbase"]}
```

```
use winapi::um::winbase::CREATE_NO_WINDOW;
let cmd = "run.bat";
Command::new(cmd).creation_flags(CREATE_NO_WINDOW).spawn().ok();
```

[Is it possible to use the standard library to spawn a process without showing the console window in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692146/is-it-possible-to-use-the-standard-library-to-spawn-a-process-without-showing-th)