# Is it possible to use the standard library to spawn a process without showing the console window in Windows?

Tags: windows, rust

This is what I have right now:

```
Command::new("/path/to/application")
  .args("-param")
  .spawn()
```

It looks like Rust uses `CreateProcessW` for running Windows processes, which allows creation flags. Perhaps there is a flag which will do what I need?

Comment: https://crates.io/search?q=windows, gl, but I don't think it's easy, windows... is based on window, maybe you want implement a windows service ?

Comment: you can use or `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag (will be no window, but will be console(invisible) created for process) or `DETACHED_PROCESS` - will be no console at all. this more efficient compare with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag (will be no additional *conhost.exe*) but application can exit, if it assume console handles exist and work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`std::os::windows::process::CommandExt::creation_flags`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/process/trait.CommandExt.html#tymethod.creation_flags). Please refer to the documentation page for the [Process Creation Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) or ideally use the constants from [winapi](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.8/winapi/um/winbase/constant.CREATE_NO_WINDOW.html).

You wrote that this is a GUI application, so I assume you don't need the console output on this one. [`DETACHED_PROCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags#DETACHED_PROCESS) does not create conhost.exe, but if you want to process the output you should use [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags#CREATE_NO_WINDOW).

I would also recommend using `start` as the command because otherwise you will have to use `cmd.exe` and this will probably delay the start by a few milliseconds.

### Example

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::os::windows::process::CommandExt;

const CREATE_NO_WINDOW: u32 = 0x08000000;
const DETACHED_PROCESS: u32 = 0x00000008;

let mut command = Command::new("cmd").args(&["/C", "start", &exe_path]);
command.creation_flags(DETACHED_PROCESS); // Be careful: This only works on windows

// If you use DETACHED_PROCESS you could set stdout, stderr, and stdin to Stdio::null() to avoid possible allocations.
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std:os::windows::process::CommandExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/process/trait.CommandExt.html) extends the `process::Command` builder with Windows-specific options when building for Windows. No constant is defined in the standard library for `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`, so you'd either need to define it yourself or use the raw value of `0x08000000`:

```
let command = Command::new("my-command")
    .args("param")
    .creation_flags(0x08000000)
    .spawn();
```