# How do I hide the console window for a process started with std::process::Command?

Tags: windows, cmd, rust

Even with `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]` at the top of my application, using `std::process::Command` creates a console window for 0.1 to 0.3 seconds. Is there a way to use `std::process::Command` in an hidden way?

In C#, I could've used `p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` — is there something similar for Rust?

Example usage of `std::process::command` that creates a console window:

```
Command::new("cmd").args(&["/C", "start", &exe_path]);
```

`exePath`  is the path to a Windows GUI Application.

Comment: @Shepmaster good point, I'll update the thread.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/process/trait.CommandExt.html#tymethod.creation_flags + one of the linked magic Windows enums?

Comment: Same question as [Spawn process without showing console window (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59692146/155423). Ideally you would have searched first and upvoted / added a bounty to that question instead of making a duplicate. If you find an answer, consider answering there and closing this question.

Comment: Do you really need to call `cmd` and have it run your application? Can't you just run your application directly with e.g. `Command::new (&exe_path)`

Comment: @Jmb yes, otherwise the app i'm starting closes as soon the rust program is over

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`std::os::windows::process::CommandExt::creation_flags`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/process/trait.CommandExt.html#tymethod.creation_flags). Please refer to the documentation page for the [Process Creation Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags).

You wrote that this is a GUI application, so I assume you don't need the console output on this one. [`DETACHED_PROCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags#DETACHED_PROCESS) does not create conhost.exe, but if you want to process the output you should use [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags#CREATE_NO_WINDOW).

I would also recommend using `start` as the command because otherwise you will have to use `cmd.exe` and this will probably delay the start by a few milliseconds.

### Example

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::os::windows::process::CommandExt;

const CREATE_NO_WINDOW: u32 = 0x08000000;
const DETACHED_PROCESS: u32 = 0x00000008;

let mut command = Command::new("cmd").args(&["/C", "start", &exe_path]);
command.creation_flags(DETACHED_PROCESS); // Be careful: This only works on windows

// If you use DETACHED_PROCESS you could set stdout, stderr, and stdin to Stdio::null() to avoid possible allocations.
```

Comment: Probably better to use the [constants from winapi](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.8/winapi/um/winbase/constant.CREATE_NO_WINDOW.html).

Comment: You are encouraged to move your answer [to the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692146/is-it-possible-to-use-the-standard-library-to-spawn-a-process-without-showing-th).

Comment: @Shepmaster Done.