# Minimising my console application in Rust to the system tray

Tags: windows, rust

I have an application made in Rust, with no GUI. This means I am not using any GUI framework, only the `log` crate to display information. However, users understandably don't want to see a terminal in their taskbar and want it within their system tray for a cleaner look instead.

I was able to successfully create the system tray icon via the `tray-icon` crate and have *some* success with the minimisation via the `winsafe` and `winapi` crates. I used `winapi` as `winsafe` did not have a specific function I was looking for.

The application does minimise, but it still appears within the taskbar. Additionally, the minimise only works if the application was ran through `cmd`. If the user ran the application by double-clicking the executable, a console was minimised but not the terminal. After doing some research, it might be the `OpenConsole.exe` process.

I have tried looking around, but no one has provided a solution within Rust that I could use. Attempting to use C++/C versions and porting them over has not worked for me.

Note: I am on Windows 11

How can I minimise my application **and** hide it from the taskbar?

```rs
/// Minimises the app. 
fn minimise_app(undo: bool) {
    // Initialise COM
    // Cannot be `_` as it would be dropped immediately
    let x = match CoInitializeEx(co::COINIT::APARTMENTTHREADED | co::COINIT::DISABLE_OLE1DDE) {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(e) => {
            log::error!("An error occured while CoInitializeEx: {}", e);
            return
        }
    };

    // Grab the taskbar
    let taskbar = match CoCreateInstance::<ITaskbarList>(
        &co::CLSID::TaskbarList,
        None,
        co::CLSCTX::INPROC_SERVER,
    ) {
        Ok(taskbar) => taskbar,
        Err(e) => {
            log::error!("An error occured while CoCreateInstance: {}", e);
            return
        }
    };

    // Grab the console window
    let console = unsafe {
        HWND::from_ptr(
            winapi::um::wincon::GetConsoleWindow().cast()
        )
    };

    // Add/remove from taskbar
    let show_cmd: co::SW;
    if undo {
        // Add to taskbar
        if let Err(e) = taskbar.AddTab(&console) {
            log::error!("An error occured while AddTab: {}", e);
            return
        }

        // Set
        show_cmd = co::SW::SHOW;
    } else {
        // Remove from taskbar
        if let Err(e) = taskbar.DeleteTab(&console) {
            log::error!("An error occured while DeleteTab: {}", e);
            return
        }

        // Set
        show_cmd = co::SW::MINIMIZE;
    }

    // Minimise/restore the window
    if !console.ShowWindow(show_cmd) {
        log::error!("An error occured while ShowWindow");
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763647/how-to-make-a-program-that-does-not-display-the-console-window

Comment: Short version: try to add `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]` at the top of your `main.rs`.

Comment: @Finomnis Unfortunately, no. It permanently hides the console and does not show it when unminimized (from the system tray)

Comment: I feel like you are trying to create a hybrid gui-but-not-gui thing. That's not really intended by windows - either something is a console app (and the terminal is shown), or something is a GUI app (and no terminal is shown, but instead the user provides a GUI). A third option is a windowless app (which is technically a GUI app, but without a window). This third option is usually used for things that only pop up in the system tray. Your program is the first time that I've seen the combination of an app that should behave like a GUI app but the GUI is the console.

Comment: Maybe I just haven't seen it yet, but I feel like you are trying to solve your problem in a way that isn't intended. :/ I'm afraid hiding to the system tray just isn't an intended part of being a console app. The whole idea of a console app is that it shouldn't be aware of things like windows.